# Difference between 'GoogleCloudMessaging' and 'Google/CloudMessaging' in PodFile

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I am using GCM for sending push notifications for iOS. In objective-C my entry in podfile was

```
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
```

When I used swift, I changed the PodFile entry to :

```
pod 'GoogleCloudMessaging', '~> 1.2'
```

With this I started getting errors :

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GGLContext", referenced from
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GGLInstanceID", referenced from:
"_kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption", referenced from:
"_kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption", referenced from:
"_kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM", referenced from:
```

Changing back to

```
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
```

is fixing the issue.

Even the documentation 
https://developers.google.com/ios/guides/cocoapods
specifies that the pods are available as the later one.

What is the difference between the two ? And why using the later one does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

`Google/CloudMessaging` has dependencies of `GGLInstanceID`, `Google/Core`, and `GoogleCloudMessaging`.

You need `Google/Core` for `GGLContext` and you need `GGLInstanceID` for `GGLInstanceID`.